# Do While Issue : Program does not stop even when do while's condition is fulfilled

Tags: java, do-while, bluej

> **This program is for finding out the difference between the Compound Interest and Simple Interest.**

**This code should terminate when I enter time as 0(Zero) and the code should run at least once.** and when I compile the code, the compiler says:

> **Class compiled - no syntax errors**

but when I run the code,the second condition "run atleast once" is fulfilled and every thing works fine but after accepting the values, It does not stop if time is entered as **0**(zero) 
**(which according to the title it should)** and it gives me the wrong answer.

Example **:**

```
p=3000
r=10
t=2
```

for the above values, the output should be `30.0` but when I run the program It gievs me the output as `-600.0` (a negetive and a wrong Difference).

```
import java.io.*;
class p6
 {
  InputStreamReader i1 =new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(i1);  
// calculating the CI and SI
public void calc()throws IOException
{   int p,t,r,si;double a, ci;char k;
    do
    {
      // getting principle
      System.out.println("Enter Principle in decimal:");           
      p = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
      // getting Rate
      System.out.println("Enter Rate in decimal    :"); 
      t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
      // getting Time
      System.out.println("Enter Time               :"); 
      r = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
      //calculating SI
      si = (p*t*r)/100;
      // calculating amount
      a = (double)p*(Math.pow((1+r/100),t));  
      // calculating CI
      ci = a - p;
      // printing Difference
      System.out.println("Difference between CI and SI = "+(ci-si)); 

     }while(t!=0);//end of DOWhile
  }// end of calc
}//end of p6
```

I'm using BlueJ to write and run my code.

I'm a beginner and just started learning java a year ago.

Please help me resolve this issue as early as possible.

Any help appreciated,

Anurag.

Comment: If nothing helps, print out t every iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this:

```
import java.io.*;
class p6
 {
  InputStreamReader i1 =new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(i1);  
// calculating the CI and SI
public void calc()throws IOException
{   double p,t,r, a, si, ci;char k;//Changed all to double.
    do
    {
      // getting principle
      System.out.println("Enter Principle in decimal:");           
      p = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());// changed to Double.parseDouble to store double value.
      // getting Rate
      System.out.println("Enter Rate in decimal    :"); 
      r = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());// changed to Double.parseDouble to store double value.
      // getting Time
      System.out.println("Enter Time               :"); 
      t = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());// changed to Double.parseDouble to store double value.
      //calculating SI
      si = (p*t*r)/100;
      // calculating amount
      a = (double)p*(Math.pow((1+r/100),t));  
      // calculating CI
      ci = a - p;
      // printing Difference
      System.out.println("Difference between CI and SI = "+(ci-si)); 

     }while(t!=0);//end of DOWhile
  }// end of calc
}//end of p6
```

Comment: Thanks! your code  with the help of other users below did the job!

Answer (score 1):

You are using integers where you should have been using doubles.

`p`, `t`, `r` and `si` are integers.

So `(1+r)/100` is, in your case `11/100` (you said `r` is `10`). The result, because this is integer division, is **zero**. So you are raising zero to whatever power. It's still zero.

Subtract the principal from zero, and you get a negative number.

If your variables were declared `double`, you would have had a non-zero result (0.11) that you could multiply your principal with.

Comment: I changed it to double as you and Blip suggested and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You called time r in your program and rate t, isnt that swapped?

Shouldn't It be

```
System.out.println("Enter Rate in decimal    :"); 
r = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
// getting Time
System.out.println("Enter Time               :"); 
t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the Scanner class. Replace

```
InputStreamReader i1 =new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(i1);
```

by
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

Moreover,

```
si = (p*t*r)/100;
```

This is where your problem is. p, t, and r are integers, so this operation will get you erroneous values. This can be solved by either changing the types of the integers into float or double, or by casting

```
si = ((double) (p*t*r))/100;
```

also, the loop will keep on executing all the lines inside even if you are supplying to with 0. To solve the issue, put this statement after the t value:

```
if(t==0)
  break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking the variable associated to Interest calculation. Not only T Even P or R should not be 0 for interest calculation so instead of checking t!=0 please check SI !=0.  As explained above multiply 0 with anything gives 0 irrespective of any other values. It avoids you multiple  variable checking of values

Comment: Thanks! It stopped executing when I changed that! Thamk yOu!

Comment: Anuragak please accept the answer if your problem is solved so that this question will not display in unaswered question section.